# Save a Struct array to NSUserDefault Swift 3?

Tags: swift, struct, swift3, nsuserdefaults

When I try to save the data during the App to use after restarting, I found by mistake when saving to NSUserDefault that I can't save directly with Structs, according to what I read NSUserDefaults can only save a small set of types: NSData, NSString, NSNumber , NSDate, NSArray containing only these types, or NSDictionary containing only these types, but I found some forms in C, which I'm not familiar with, and some in Swift but I do not quite understand,besides I can't find the way to do it **with Struct "Carreras" that is embedded in the Struct "CursosG"**. I'm looking for an effective way to be able to run this in Swift 3. This is my code:

```
struct CursosG {
    let id: Int
    let nrc: String
    let profesor: String
    let carreras: [Carreras]
    let dia: String
    let bloque: String
    let sala: String
    let idcurso: Int
    let comentario: String
    let curso: String

    init(id: Int, nrc: String, profesor: String, carreras: [Carreras], dia: String, bloque: String, sala: String, idcurso: Int, comentario: String, curso: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.nrc = nrc
        self.profesor = profesor
        self.carreras = carreras
        self.dia = dia
        self.bloque = bloque
        self.sala = sala
        self.idcurso = idcurso
        self.comentario = comentario
        self.curso = curso
    }    

    struct Carreras {
        let id: Int
        let nombre: String
        let semestre: Int

        init(id: Int, nombre: String, semestre: Int) {
            self.id = id
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.semestre = semestre
        }
    }
}

...

var CursoAllG = [CursoG]()

...

let curso = CursosG(id: idT, nrc: nrcT, profesor: profesorT, carreras: carrers as! [CursosG.Carreras], dia: diaT, bloque: bloqueT, sala: salaT, idcurso: idcursoT, comentario: comentarioT, curso: cursoT)
CursosAllG.append(curso)

...

UserDefaults.standard.set(CursosAllG, forKey: "cursosAllG")
```

How should I convert the struct?

Comment: Have you thought about CoreData rather than UserDefaults? Storing objects in UserDefaults can be messy, and CoreData isn't designed to store multiple of a single type of object (if say you want to store 10+ CursoG objects). While you could serialize CursoG and Carrera for storage in UserDefaults, this may not be the best way depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your struct data to NSData and then you will be able to store it. Here is a so link which describes it [Structs to NSData to Structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373545/structs-to-nsdata-to-structs)

However I still feel you should use a dictionary instead of using structs as it has cross platform support.