# NSData vs NSValue ? how to encapsulate a C-structure in sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsdata, nsvalue

I'm trying work out the way to use `sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData` as a way to retune a handful of MIDI notes in a music app. I'd like the `ViewController` to send a MIDI message to the `Synth` class to change the tuning of 10 notes. The standard MIDI System Exclusive message format for retuning one note looks like this

```
                 F0 7F <device ID> 08 02 tt ll [kk xx yy zz] F7.
```

*[`legend: tt ll [kk xx yy zz]`](http://www.microtonal-synthesis.com/MIDItuning.html) (NB -slightly different to MIDI 1.0 Detailed Specification 4.2, p.49)*

With `typedef struct` it would be possible to use a single `float` instead of a `uint8_t` to represent tuning frequency, e.g.

**PlayViewController.h**

```
    typedef struct
    {
    uint8_t SYSEX_SysexHeader;                // oxF0h;     // System Exclusive Header
    uint8_t SYSEX_UniversalRealTimeHeader;    // ox7Fh;     // Universal RealTime Header
    uint8_t SYSEX_myPhone;                    // ox00h;     // ID of target device (e.g. iPhone)
    uint8_t SYSEX_subID1;                     // ox08h;     // sub-ID #1 (MIDI Tuning Standard)
    uint8_t SYSEX_subID2;                     // ox02h;     // sub-ID #2 (note change)
    uint8_t SYSEX_tuningProgramNumber;        // ox0h;      // tuning program number (0 -127)
    uint8_t SYSEX_numberOfKeys;               // ox10h;     // number of changes

    uint8_t SYSEX_key0;
    float   TUNING_pitch_0;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key1;
    float   TUNING_pitch_1;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key2;
    float   TUNING_pitch_2;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key3;
    float   TUNING_pitch_3;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key4;
    float   TUNING_pitch_4;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key5;
    float   TUNING_pitch_5;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key6;
    float   TUNING_pitch_6;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key7;
    float   TUNING_pitch_7;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key8;
    float   TUNING_pitch_8;

    uint8_t SYSEX_key9;
    float   TUNING_pitch_9;

    uint8_t eox;                                // OxF7h;       //

    }
    TuneEvent;
```

and still in .h

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SYSEX)
    {
    SYSEX_SysexHeader               = 240,
    SYSEX_UniversalRealTimeHeader   = 127,
    SYSEX_myPhone                   = 0,
    SYSEX_subID1                    = 8,
    SYSEX_subID2                    = 2,
    SYSEX_tuningProgramNumber       = 0,
    SYSEX_numberOfKeysToBeChanged   = 1,
    SYSEX_key0                      = 61,
    SYSEX_key1                      = 62,
    SYSEX_key2                      = 63,
    SYSEX_key3                      = 64,
    SYSEX_key4                      = 65,
    SYSEX_key5                      = 66,
    SYSEX_key6                      = 67,
    SYSEX_key7                      = 68,
    SYSEX_key8                      = 69,
    SYSEX_key9                      = 70,
    SYSEX_eox                       = 247
    };

    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TUNING)
    {
    TUNING_pitch0,
    TUNING_pitch1,
    TUNING_pitch2,
    TUNING_pitch3,
    TUNING_pitch4,
    TUNING_pitch5,
    TUNING_pitch6,
    TUNING_pitch7,
    TUNING_pitch8,
    TUNING_pitch9
    };

    float TUNING_float(TUNING micro);
```

and finally for the floating point values ... *[(thanks to this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44252396/2348597)*

**PlayViewController.m**

```
    float TUNING_float(TUNING micro) 
    {
    switch (micro) 
        {
        case TUNING_pitch0:
            return  579.4618f;
        case TUNING_pitch1:
            return  607.0552f;
        case TUNING_pitch2:
            return  662.2421f;
        case TUNING_pitch3:
            return  708.2311f;
        case TUNING_pitch4:
            return  772.6157f;
        case TUNING_pitch5:
            return  809.4070f;
        case TUNING_pitch6:
            return  882.9894f;
        case TUNING_pitch7:
            return  910.5828f;
        case TUNING_pitch8:
            return  993.3631f;
        case TUNING_pitch9:
            return  1030.1540f;
        default:
            return   0.0f;
        }
    }
```

However when I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373588/2348597) I began to ask how I might go about preparing a MIDI data packet based on `NSData` that `sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData` will send. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517970/2348597) recommends `NSValue` as the better way to encapsulate a C-structure like the one I'm trying to create so I'm confused. If that really is the case, I'm puzzled why Apple would introduce a method like [`sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiounitmidiinstrument/1387812-sendmidisysexevent?language=objc).

My question is: based on the message format *(outlined in my code above)*, how would I prepare `midiData` in order to send it using this method ?

**CONCLUSION**

In response to the accepted answer, length of "raw binary data", defined in terms of *number of bytes* rather than *type of data*, explains the salient difference between `NSData` and `NSValue`. This would also suggest `sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData` was only designed to handle bytes of data i.e. `uint8_t` and not `float.` In other words, the sensible option is to express frequency values using bytes as per the following extract from the MIDI Tuning Standard

> ```
>     yy = MSB of fractional part (1/128 semitone = 100/128 cents = .78125 cent units)
>     zz = LSB of fractional part (1/16384 semitone = 100/16384 cents = .0061 cent units)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `NSData` and `NSValue` are wrappers around "raw binary data", yet with a different intent and with a different way in defining the length of the binary data.

`NSValue` targets in boxing scalar types like `int`, `float` (but also a `struct`), and the interface of `NSValue` is designed to pass the length of the "data" by means of the type. Hence, it is not possible to encapsulate objects of variable length (like VLA or C-strings) within an NSValue, since the size of the data cannot be derived from the type information ([cf. NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html)):

> The type you specify must be of constant length. You cannot store C
>   strings, variable-length arrays and structures, and other data types
>   of indeterminate length in an NSValue—you should use NSString or
>   NSData objects for these types.

`NSData` is meant as a box for arbitrary byte buffers. So it has an interface through which you can define the length of the "raw binary data" in terms of bytes (and *not in terms of a type*).

Concerning your question, as the MIDI-interface in `sendMIDISysExEvent:(NSData *)midiData` expects an `NSData`-object, the only (meaningful) way is to pass your object as an `NSData`-object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Stephen, it certainly clarified things. See my response. Thanks